# How to setStrokeColor for com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView programmatically

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-cardview, material-components-android

I tried the code below in my adapter class, but it is not working.

```
myViewHolder.cardview1.setStrokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.selected_color));
```

Comment: Am ask MaterialCardView stroke colour set programmatically,  not normal card view, I try this code in my  XML file  card_view:strokeColor="@color/selected_color" ,its working fine but I need to set programmatically

Comment: Check this - https://android--code.blogspot.com/2019/01/android-materialcardview-example.html

Comment: in XML file app:strokeColor="#ff3939" its working fine but i need to set progrmmatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61181745/4429637 answer is worked for me

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, to solve it just add the `invalidate()` method:

```
myViewHolder.cardview1.setStrokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.selected_color));
myViewHolder.cardview1.invalidate();
```

This updates the view.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in Material Components version `1.2.0`. I don't have to call `invalidate()` anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the [**`setStrokeColor`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/card/MaterialCardView.html#setStrokeColor(int)) method:

```
MaterialCardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.card);
cardView.setStrokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color....));
```

You have to set the width of the stroke because the default value is **`0dp`**.

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/card"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp"
    ..>
```

Otherwise use the [**`setStrokeWidth`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/card/MaterialCardView.html#setstrokewidth)  method.

[image]

Comment: I already  try the same code in my adapter class but is not working for me, I set app:strokeWidth="2dp"  in my XML

Comment: Are you using v 1.0 or 1.1?

Comment: @Kannan Also did you try the same code without the adapter?